# QRcode php save in file

Tags: php, png, qr-code

I would like save my Qrcode as "qrcode.png" in on my computer. I'm using this library : https://github.com/endroid/QrCode

I used the `$qrCode->writeFile(__DIR__.'/qrcode.png');`
But i can't found my image as a png file

this is my generate.php code :

```
    <?php

header("Content-Type: image/png");
require "vendor/autoload.php";

use Endroid\QrCode\QrCode;

$qrcode = new QrCode($_GET['text']);

echo $qrcode->writeString();

// Set advanced options
$qrCode
    ->setWriterByName('png')
    ->setMargin(10)
    ->setEncoding('UTF-8')
    ->setErrorCorrectionLevel(ErrorCorrectionLevel::HIGH)
    ->setForegroundColor(['r' => 0, 'g' => 0, 'b' => 0])
    ->setBackgroundColor(['r' => 255, 'g' => 255, 'b' => 255])
    ->setLabel('Scan the code', 16, __DIR__.'/../assets/noto_sans.otf', LabelAlignment::CENTER)
    ->setLogoPath(__DIR__.'/../assets/symfony.png')
    ->setLogoWidth(150)
    ->setValidateResult(false)
;

// Directly output the QR code
header('Content-Type: '.$qrcode->getContentType());
echo $qrCode->writeString();

// Save it to a file
$qrCode->writeFile(__DIR__.'/qrcode.png');

?>
```

AnD this is my php_error.log :

> [18-Nov-2017 10:48:10 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: qrCode in C:\wamp64\www\QR_code\generate.php on line 14
>
> [18-Nov-2017 10:48:10 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
>
> [18-Nov-2017 10:48:10 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp64\www\QR_code\generate.php:0
>
> [18-Nov-2017 10:48:10 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function setWriterByName() on null in C:\wamp64\www\QR_code\generate.php on line 14
>
> [18-Nov-2017 10:48:10 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
>
> [18-Nov-2017 10:48:10 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp64\www\QR_code\generate.php:0

EDIT (after change my qrCode by qrcode):

[18-Nov-2017 11:00:58 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ErrorCorrectionLevel' not found in C:\wamp64\www\QR_code\generate.php on line 17

[18-Nov-2017 11:00:58 UTC] PHP Stack trace:

[18-Nov-2017 11:00:58 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp64\www\QR_code\generate.php:0

(when i delete the 'ErrorCorrectionLevel' same error for 'LabelAlignment')

Thanks for help.

Comment: Do you have write access to the folder? Check your servers error log if there are any clues there.

Comment: this my php_error.log :[18-Nov-2017 10:48:10 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: qrCode in C:\wamp64\www\QR_code\generate.php on line 14

[18-Nov-2017 10:48:10 UTC] PHP Stack trace:

[18-Nov-2017 10:48:10 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp64\www\QR_code\generate.php:0

[18-Nov-2017 10:48:10 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function setWriterByName() on null in C:\wamp64\www\QR_code\generate.php on line 14

[18-Nov-2017 10:48:10 UTC] PHP Stack trace:

[18-Nov-2017 10:48:10 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp64\www\QR_code\generate.php:0

Comment: Please edit your question and add the error message. It's pretty unreadable as a comment.

Comment: At a quick glance, you're defining the variable `$qrcode` but later you're using `$qrCode`. Variables are case sensitive.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson sorry, is that ok now ?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Did you check my last comment?

Comment: I just edit my post with the my actual php_error.log

Comment: You should take another look at their example in their repo. You need to add `use`-statements for all the classes you're going to use

Comment: qr-code, aka qrcode, it's a bad class where the only examples provided don't work. waste of time.